# How to create a dummy AVPlayerItem with a real duration?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I'm using an `AVPlayer` to play `CAKeyFrameAnimations` on a `AVSynchronizedLayer`. In order to keep the player playing as I do not play an `AVAsset` during the animation, I set the `forwardPlaybackEndTime` of the `AVPlayerItem` to the desired animation's duration. Unfortunately. It seems impossible to `seekToTime:` during this `forwardPlaybackEndTime` as the `AVPlayer` always goes back to the beginning. Probably because it tries to seek into the `AVplayerItem`'s duration.

How could I create a dummy AVPlayerItem with a real duration to trick the AVPlayer to play some empty `AVPlayerItem` and letting me `seekToTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `seekToTime` will only seek into the `AVPlayerItem's` duration. Thus it is required to create a dummy player item to generate a seek-able duration. In order to do so rapidly, one need to create a dummy AVplayerItem. Here's an example of implementation to generate such an item. It's long but it's required. Good luck!

```
@interface FakeAsset ()

+ (CVPixelBufferRef)blackImagePixelBuffer;

@end

@implementation FakeAsset

+ (void)assetWithDuration:(CMTime)duration
        completitionBlock:(void (^)(AVAsset *))callBack
{
    NSError * error      = nil;
    NSString * assetPath = nil;
    NSUInteger i         = 0;
    do
    {
        assetPath =
        [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dummyAsset%i.m4v",i]];
        i++;
    }
    while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:assetPath
                                                isDirectory:NO]);

    NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:assetPath];

    NSParameterAssert(fileURL);

    AVAssetWriter * videoWriter =
    [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:fileURL
                              fileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4V
                                 error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary * compression  =
  @{
    AVVideoAverageBitRateKey      : @10,
    AVVideoProfileLevelKey        : AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main31,
    AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : @300
    };

    NSDictionary * outputSettings =
  @{
    AVVideoCodecKey                 : AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : compression,
    AVVideoWidthKey                 : @120,
    AVVideoHeightKey                : @80
    };

    AVAssetWriterInput * videoWriterInput =
    [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                       outputSettings:outputSettings];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);

    NSDictionary * parameters =
    @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
      (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey           : @120,
      (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey          : @80
      };

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor * adaptor =
    [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:parameters];
    NSParameterAssert(adaptor);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);

    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter startWriting]);

    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    [videoWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue
                                            usingBlock:^
    {
        int frame = 0;
        while (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData)
        {
            if (frame < 2)
            {
                CMTime frameTime = frame ? duration : kCMTimeZero;
                CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self blackImagePixelBuffer];

                [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer
                      withPresentationTime:frameTime];

                CVBufferRelease(buffer);

                ++frame;
            }
            else
            {
                [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
                [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:duration];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^()
                     {
                         NSLog(@"did finish writing the video!");
                         AVURLAsset * asset =
                         [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoWriter.outputURL];
                         callBack(asset);
                     }];
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
}

+ (CVPixelBufferRef)blackImagePixelBuffer
{
    NSDictionary * options =
    @{
      (id)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey         : @YES,
      (id)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : @YES
      };

    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status =
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 120, 80, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options, &pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    void * pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, 120, 80, 8, 4*120, rgbColorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context,CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 120.f, 80.f));
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier if you just create an `AVMutableComposition` with a `AVMutableCompositionTrack` in which you put an empty range of the desired duration using `insertEmptyTimeRange:`.

Then use this composition to create your AVPlayerItem - `playerItemWithAsset:` as it is a subclass of `AVAsset`.

This won't require any generating and writing then reading and is much less code as well.

Comment: Except your solution doesn't work. I've tried it a long time ago. Empty time range is… empty.

Comment: I just tried it in before I gave the answer. I'm developing now an app that deals with video. I changed just for the test my composition and instead of adding a real asset inserted an empty range and it was working. I even tried to leave the audio only from the asset and that was also OK. I know that it's an empty time range which is still a video track and acts as that. The only thing I noticed though was that it takes more time to reach playable status for the player and the player item than when using a real asset.

Comment: Just a quick update... It really works, however I just found out that only in some cases - it doesn't work if you apply instructions to the composition. If you have just cuts without any extra manipulations of the tracks it works fine. So in my current project it's useless and I ended up inserting a very short black video and stretch it out to the duration I need. Not very happy with that but it's an acceptable workaround.